# React-native not building after upgrade to version 0.39

Tags: react-native

After upgrade project to version 0.39 on **Android** im getting: `Error: Requiring unknown module "0". If you sure module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install""`. And on iOS:

```
2016-12-27 12:08:14.802 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:72] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x608000380750> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080000a5d00>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2016-12-27 12:08:15.749 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTBatchedBridge.m:505] Failed to execute source code: Unhandled JS Exception: Error
2016-12-27 12:08:15.750 [fatal][tid:main] Unhandled JS Exception: Error
2016-12-27 12:08:15.751 [98772:687954] -[RCTJSStackFrame objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000004f6f0
```

Comment: please show the code

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a mismatch between your native code and your JavaScript code. Clear out all your caches so that you are building and running a clean app:

- Delete your node_modules folder and run "npm install" again (or use yarn if you want this step to be fast). Make sure package.json specifies the latest version of React Native that you expect.
- Delete your Android "build" folders ("git clean -dfxn" might help to find them) and your global iOS "DerivedData" folder (lots of guides online)
- Uninstall your app from the iOS simulator or your iPhone
- Delete your app data on your Android device and uninstall your app
- Clear your Watchman state with "watchman watch-del-all"
- Start the React Native server with "npm start -- --reset-cache" to clear the packager cache

Then build and run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused due a difference between required version of React to React-Native that i`m using. So, the problem was discovered using `npm list`command. After that just run `npm install reat@X.Y`where X.Y is the version.